# Avoid repeating the template parameter for accessing enum in class template

Tags: c++, templates, enums

Consider a class template that implements a container which includes an option for choosing its storage place.

```
template<class T>
class Container {
public:
  enum StorageOption {A,B};
  Container(StorageOption opt_): option(opt_) {}
private:
  StorageOption option;
};
```

Here `StorageOption` was chosen to be a member since it is only used in the class.

Now, to instantiate the class I would need to repeat the template parameter, like:

```
{
  Container<int> c( Container<int>::A );
}
```

Is there a way to avoid repeating the parameter and at the same time have `StorageOption` being a member or is there a better way of implementing the option?

Comment: I don't see how hmjd's idea could possibly work.

Comment: Have you tried this 'using type= Container<int>::StorageOption'?

Comment: There is an ugly solution that you could put the enum out of the class and name it `ContainerStorageOption`.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

It is usually achieved by defining it in a base class.

```
class ContainerBase {
public:
  enum StorageOption {A,B};
};


template<class T>
class Container : public ContainerBase{
public:
  Container(StorageOption opt_): option(opt_) {}
private:
  StorageOption option;
};

Container<int> c( ContainerBase::A );
```

Comment: Right! I am always thinking for a thing as small as this polymorphism is a hammer. But I guess that's how C++ is meant to be.

Comment: @Frank, there  is no polymorphism, `ContainerBase` isn't polymorphic

Comment: @Frank this isn't composition ether, it's just inheritance

Comment: @WillemD'haeseleer sure it's inheritance. But if you look how it's implemented in the compiler you'll notice that it's implemented as composition. A derived class inherits the members from all of it's base classes via composition. Polymorphism is an exception to this.

Answer (score 0):

I have been battling with this problem myself and I don't really like the need for a base class as well as how you need to repeat the base class specifier when wanting to use enum classes. I came up with this solution:

```
namespace FuncEnum{
    enum class FuncNeighbor{
        FLOOR, CEILING, SELF
    };
    enum class FuncDirection{
        BACK, FRONT, BACKNFRONT
    };
    enum class FuncVar{
        X, Y
    };
} using namespace FuncEnum;

template<typename... Types>
class Func {};
```

This way you can have globally available enum classes with minimal specification. It's not likely that collision happens between < class nickname > < enum class name > but even if there were, the using declaration should shadow (?) whatever global identifier about to interfere (which, in a peculiar case can be undone again with another using declaration).